# Not create and write into file, Python-3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a problem: a function must create a file and write into it a word when I left-click on the word and also this function must check if this word already exists in the file, but file not create and write

Here's the code I have so far:

```
def f_save_word_to_file(word):
    if word not in [ x.strip() for x in open(os.path.expanduser (save_word_to_file_fname)).readlines() ]:
        print(word, file = open(os.path.expanduser (save_word_to_file_fname), 'a'))
```

variable:

```
save_word_to_file_fname = '~/saved_words'
```

os.path library connected

```
import os, subprocess, sys
```

Another function that that's invoked by a right mouse button click works without a problem (I've tried to swap these functions but it didn't solve my problem).

I've tired changing the path, creating the file myself, changing the fileright with `777` but nothing worked.

Maybe anyone here knows where the mistake is?

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: You may have an easier time debugging this if you remove all the tkinter mouse-button-detecting code and just call this function straight from the main scope. The fewer lines of code you need to replicate the problem, the better.

Comment: try `'a+'` rather than `'a'`

Comment: Do you get some kind of prize for shoving the entire function into 2 lines?  Otherwise, it would simplify your debugging tremendously to put one step per line, and check the result.  Open your file.  (Debug if needed) Read the lines.  (Debug if needed) Check if the word is in the lines.  (Debug if needed) If not, open the file.  (Debug if needed) Write to it.  (Debug if needed)

Comment: Kevin, I  removed all mouse-button-detecting code, now I have only left-click-mouse code, but not worked

Comment: Tomos Williams, I tried "a+" before, not helped

Comment: Scott Mermelstein, I try rewrite this function now as you said, but I don't know how I can debug it, I dont know how I can start this script in terminal because this script run with lua script(for mpv player) and I can click on word only in mpv window

Comment: When you don't know how to set up your debugger, you can always use `print` statements to see what your status is.  It's just easier to check what's going on when each step is in its own line.  Incidentally, separating your open with the implicit "r" from the open with the specific "a" might solve your problem, too.

Comment: At this moment I have run script into eric IDE and have 1 error  Python 3.6.4+ (default, Feb 12 2018, 08:25:03) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on debian, Standard
>>> [py part] Starting interSubs ...
Exception "unhandled IndexError"
list index out of range
File: /home/camel/.config/mpv/scripts/interSubs.py, Line: 1057  This error almost in end of file, after my function, now I'll try write separate function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function work:

```
def f_save_word_to_file(word):
    if ( os.path.isfile(os.path.expanduser(save_word_to_file_fname)) and word not in [ x.strip() for x in open(os.path.expanduser(save_word_to_file_fname)).readlines() ] ) or not os.path.isfile(os.path.expanduser(save_word_to_file_fname)):
        print(word, file = open(os.path.expanduser(save_word_to_file_fname), 'a'))
```

Thanks all